# Magento 2 Remove sku initials from url_rewrite table

Tags: magento2

i have url_rewrite table in my magento 2.1 setup in which i have url structure like this

www.exaple.com/name-of-product.html

which is desirable , but many product have the url structure like this

www.exaple.com/name-of-product-sku-2054.html so at the end they contain product sku which is sku-2054

i need to remove all such occurrence from the database where the url is like  www.exaple.com/name-of-product-sku-2054.html and what to change them to www.exaple.com/name-of-product.html

i went through url_rewrite which i believe contains these urls and found out that there are around 68k entries that would be needed to change .

[image]

can anyone suggest how can i do that without getting into the problem with duplicate urls also  will it cause any harm if i do this by replacing the values from the column request_path from table url_rewrite . Do i need to change data from other tables also?

Answer (score 1):

You can run this MySQL command, Backup the table `url_rewrite` before perform

`` UPDATE `url_rewrite` AS a INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS b ON b.`entity_id` = a.`entity_id` SET `request_path` = REPLACE(`request_path`, b.`sku`, ''); ``

Comment: thanks for the query @Nozomy , but i am also concerned about duplicate entries that i would need to take care of for example there are url in the database like "out-the shop-sr-201.html"  , "out-the shop-sr-203.html" , "out-the shop-sr-204.html" , all these product are different but on running the above query it might thow error of duplicate urls.

Comment: The easy solution is to create a php file to run the update query:

Comment: `$conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass,$db);`
`$url_rewrite = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM url_rewrite a LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity b ON b.entity_id = a.entity_id WHERE a.entity_type = 'product'");`
`$data_url_rewrite = array();`
`while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($url_rewrite , MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {`
            `$data_url_rewrite [] = $row;`
`}`
`foreach($data_url_rewrite as $url){`
   `$new_request_path = str_replace($url['sku'], '', $url['request_path']);`
  // check if new path doesn't exist then update request_path, 
`}`